# JTable not refreshing after removing rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have my Jtable inside a ScrollPane which in-turn is inside a Panel. So Whenever I remove a row using

```
model.removeRow(row_number);
```

it does remove the row(verified by calling model.getRowCount()) but the view remains the same.

```
public void createTable(){
    model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
    table = new JTable(model);

    table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    table.setEnabled(false);
    table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    scrollPane_2 = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane_2.setBounds(10, 16, 554, 89);
    scrollPane_2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    panel_6.add(scrollPane_2);

}
```

I have tried revalidate(), repaint() on all the three (panel, table and scrollpane), also

```
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

but still the view dosen't change...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're throwing away the `JTable` based on your `model` when you reassign the variable `table`.

```
table = new JTable(model);

table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```

When you remove the row from `model`, the `JTable` you are displaying never hears about it since it has its own model.